# HttpClient: "HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request"

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm trying to get a image using HttpClient and I'm getting this error:

> HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request

Using WebClient with DownloadData method, works fine.

```
var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { CookieContainer = cookieContainer })
using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", "pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
    client.GetAsync("cookieGenerateUrl").Wait();

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("Accept");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "image/webp,image/apng,image/*,*/*;q=0.8");
    var imagem = client.GetByteArrayAsync(imageUrl).Result;
}
```

What is the equivalent to WebClient.DownloadData on HttpClient class?

Comment: provide more data. what r the other properties of the client object?

Comment: Stop using `.Result` and `.Wait()` on async calls. Await the response. Please see [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

Comment: @mason Is there some difference on console app? If i use await, what will happen with the main thread?

Comment: In a console app, it's best to use C# 7.1 so you can have an async main method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the problem here is that you are calling `client.GetByteArrayAsync` with no proper handling of the awaitable.

the fix is:

```
var res = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(url);
```

or

```
byte[] arr;
client.GetByteArrayAsync(url).ContinueWith((x) => arr = x.Result);
```

Comment: Ok, it is works, but i don't know why. Can u explain? Why I can't just use .Result after of GetByteArrayAsync?

Comment: Because it’s asynchronous and at the time you requested the Result it wasn’t there yet

Comment: It doesn’t. I would recommend to learn more about async and await